# disabling default behavior of drop-down-menu / html-select fails on apple-mobile-web-app-capable

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, drop-down-menu, preventdefault

The story: I do not want reinvent the wheel, but for an intranet web app I am developing a normalized toolbox (--> SAME behavior on any OS / browser !!!) for regular input fields, specially drop-down-menu fields (html-selectbox), of which the content list needs to be searchable by user due to too much entries. With up to 27k entries scrolling makes not any sense. Well, this part works fine.

Now the problem: To be able to click on a selectbox but do other things with it, I am using this function (which I found anywhere around here on stackoverflow, sorry I cannot find the link at the moment)

```
$(document).on('mousedown',function(e){
    console.log(e.target.nodeName); // "select" or "option" ?
    var elm = $(e.target);
    if (elm.is('select') || elm.closest('select').length) {
        if (elm.is('select')) var sel = elm;
        else var sel = elm.closest('select');
        e.preventDefault();
        sel.blur();
        window.focus();
        //------ do other things with the select box
    }
});
```

This is totally crossbrowser stable and makes the selectbox accessible for the pointer (mouse or touch on mobile devices) and supresses the default behavior of the element at the same time.

Today I've implemented the entire script to the main project. As long as I open the project in regular browsers (desktop and mobile as well), everything's still fine and runs as expected. But once the project is opened via the home screen link as web app, in iOS (actual iPad) the default behavior of the element appears again, together with my own one. Web view in android chrome is still OK.

Any suggestions for mobile safari web app mode ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll answer my own question.

After I gave it up to find the reason for this unexpected Safari behavior, I did workaround it, which turned out useful also for CSS styling of the SELECT element.

My solution is to use a wrapper DIV, and set the SELECT to `pointer-events:none;`. Until now everything works fine, on all OS and browsers, incl. web app mode in mobile Safari and mobile Chrome.

The javascript function now looks like this:

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){
    var elm = $(e.target);
    if (elm.is('div.selectwrapper')) {
        var sel = elm.find('select'); // --- targeted SELECT element
        // --- other stuff to do with sel
    }
});
```

And I want to provide the mentioned CSS code as well:

```
div.selectwrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

div.selectwrapper::before, div.selectwrapper::after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 7px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #666;
    pointer-events: none;
}

div.selectwrapper::before {
    right: 14px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

div.selectwrapper::after {
    right: 31px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background: none;
    border:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #555;
    width: 244px;
    height: 38px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-right: 46px #eee solid;
    pointer-events: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 100%;
}

select:not(*:root) { //------ Safari only hack
    padding-left: 10px; 
}
```

The optical result is a SELECT element which looks the same cross browser / OS, pure css, no images.

And the functional result, as answer to my question, is that the DIV is clicked and the script identifies the inner SELECT element as data source as well as the target for user selection changes. At every time I can decide, whether to wrap the SELECT element server side before HTML output, or use jquery to wrap it. `$('select').wrap('<div class="selectwrapper" />');`